# Can't read value from textbox into javascript variable

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net, html, json

Hello I am trying to read a textbox(runatserver)  after is gets populated form the server  into a javascript variable,but it gives me a console error that "can't read form NULL" however the text box is populated by the string I want to read

this is my text box:

```
 <form runat="server">

        <asp:TextBox ID="ServerSideTextBox" runat="server" />
    </form>
```

This is how I am populating it in C#:

```
ServerSideTextBox.Text= Object_JSON_Class.JSON_DataTable(dt);
```

it gets the right data also shows the right data string but the PROBLEM is when I try to read the value of the text box like this:

```
 var oServerSideTextBox= document.getElementById("ServerSideTextBox"); 
var oServerJSON_String=eval("("+oServerSideTextBox.value+")");
```

I get a  console error that I can't read form NULL,but the text box does have the string I want to read into javascript variable,please help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
 var txtToIncr = document.getElementById('<%=ServerSideTextBox.ClientID%>')
```

Check out this [link](http://wiki.asp.net/page.aspx/483/referencing-server-controls-from-javascript/), about reading ASP.Net controls through javascript

Comment: check your generated HTML and see what is being rendered against serversidetextbox id

Comment: I saw that too the id is the same i.e serversidetextbox (ignoring caps)

Comment: try var t = document.forms[0]['ServerSideTextBox'].value; and see if it gets the value

Comment: nope ain't working,I have also read the link you have given me,according to it .ClientID should solve the problem but its not,maybe its because of something else then ID mismatch,can't figure out where I am going wrong tho

Comment: @Snedden27 even I am confused, just for testing try in your C#, ServerSideTextBox.Text = "Sample Text"; and then see if it is working

Comment: In that case, are you sure that the error is generated by the piece of code: var oServerSideTextBox= document.getElem....; Maybe you have an error on previous lines of javascript

Comment: the error is infact generated by the next line when I try to assign my javascript variable i.e the second line I given in the code i.e
var oServerJSON_String=eval("("+oServerSideTextBox.value+")");

Comment: it did work,seems like I had not removed  '_type' which I had added after the id because of some of the answers I received

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

`var oServerSideTextBox= document.getElementById("<%=ServerSideTextBox.ClientID%>");`

If that does not work, try something like this:

`var oServerSideTextBox= document.getElementById("<%=ServerSideTextBox.ClientID%>_text");`

Components are assigned different ID's when rendered by the client's browser. You can take a look [here](http://www.devx.com/tips/Tip/28332) for more information.

Answer (score 0):

put this on yout textbox `ClientIDMode="Static"`

Answer (score 0):

Your server textbox's ID will be different if you use it in a master page structure , try finding its id.Because its actual id might be something like this ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_ServerSideTextbox.Check that.

Assign a class to yout textbox then try this to find the id.

```
$('.textbox').on('blur', function() {

        var error = this.id;
        alert(error);
                                       )};
```

Comment: I am not using master page structure right now, and how do I find the actual id  the text box?

Comment: @Snedden27 , did you try that

Comment: hmm its laughable but the ID in the pop-up is same ie ServerSideTextBox ,

Comment: @Snedden27 , strange I ran into similar problem sometime ago , my issue was the id.

Comment: @Snedden27 , did you check this in other browsers also

Answer (score 0):

Reading the comments. I think you're referring to the wrong textbox-ID..
So I made a small test-thingy: this should work.. If not look into the source from your HTML - there you can see the ID.

```
<script type='text/javascript'>
    function testvalue() {
        var oServerSideTextBox = document.getElementById('<%=ServerSideTextBox.ClientID%>');
        if (oServerSideTextBox == null) {
            alert('this is null');
        }
        else {
            alert(oServerSideTextBox.value);
        }
    }
</script>



<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
    <div>
        <asp:TextBox ID="ServerSideTextBox" runat="server" Text="Testvalue" />
        <input type='button' onclick='testvalue();' value='Click' />
    </div>
    </form>
</body>
```